# Утечка памяти при вращении изображения. Как избежать?

Tags: c#, .net

По рекомендации [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) из [прошлой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484673/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-system-tray/485193#485193), выделяю сей вопрос в отдельную.

Собственно проблема в указана в заголовке. Есть код и при его работе постепенно увеличивается отъедаемый приложением объем оперативной памяти. Чем больше то изображение, с которым работает код, тем заметней эта утечка. Как исправить ситуацию?

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImgRotate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap btmpIcn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            btmpIcn = notifyIcon1.Icon.ToBitmap();
        }

        int an;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (an >= 350)
                an = 0;
            else
                an += 10;

            notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(RotateImage(btmpIcn, an).GetHicon());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// method to rotate an image either clockwise or counter-clockwise
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="img">the image to be rotated</param>
        /// <param name="rotationAngle">the angle (in degrees).
        /// NOTE: 
        /// Positive values will rotate clockwise
        /// negative values will rotate counter-clockwise
        /// </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
        {
            //create an empty Bitmap image
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

            //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
            gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

            //now rotate the image
            gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

            gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

            //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
            //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
            gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

            //dispose of our Graphics object
            gfx.Dispose();

            //return the image
            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: то-есть  вы на каждый тик порождаете новый битмап и хотите чтоб утечек не было? а диспозить предыдущее состояние не пробовали?

Comment: Недостаточно изучил что автоматически освобождается, а что вручную диспозить нужно... Благодарю за подсказку. Проблема решилась.

Comment: создайте необходимые изображения, соберите их в коллекцию и используйте их для вывода в tray.

Comment: @Stack коллекция может например зависеть от входящего сообщения ;)

Comment: _"Недостаточно изучил что автоматически освобождается, а что вручную диспозить нужно"_ -- у всех объектов с IDisposable при ненадобности надо вызывать Dispose()

Comment: @Stack Dispose(true)

Comment: @Dmitry _"коллекция может например зависеть от входящего сообщения"_ -- как часто они приходя? мы же не кино в tray показываем. пришло сообщение. в отдельном потоке созаем новый рисунок, и меняем коллекцию

Comment: @Dmitry _"Dispose(true)"_ -- у [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) нет метода Dispose с параметрами.

Comment: @Stack это абстрактное измышление, ведь изображение изначально может не находится локально, чтоб его в статическую коллекцию запихнуть

Comment: @Dmitry _"это абстрактное измышление, ведь изображение изначально может не находится локально"_ -- посмотрите текст вопроса. там метод RotateImage и timer1_Tick

Comment: @Stack, да, нет, но его как бы надо реализовать, чтоб сообщить коллектору что надо бы его в первую очередь грохнуть, а то вдруг он окажется большого объема и попадет на 3 левел

Comment: @Stack я вижу только что `notifyIcon1` живет где-то еще

Comment: @Stack, про вариант с коллекцией изображений знаю, но он мне показался слишком простым :-)

Comment: @Raf-9600 ну ка бы вариант с коллекцией изначально заберет всю память которую вы выбираете изначально, так что диспоз наше все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть [исходники .NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), то видно, что вызов [Icon.FromHandle(IntPtr)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,559) транслируется в вызов [Icon(IntPtr, takeOwnership=false)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,71).
Чтобы избежать утечки памяти, надо для каждого IntPtr, который был получен при вызове GetHicon, вызывать DestroyIcon, после того как IntPtr перестал быть нужен.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
```

И у Bitmap, который больше не нужен, надо вызывать метод [Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx);

Чтобы каждый раз по таймеру не создавать новые Bitmap, как я уже говорил в комментарии [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485198/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/485204#comment563679_485198), надо создать необходимые изображения, собрать их в коллекцию и использовать их для вывода в tray.

---

Можно конвертировать Bitmap в Icon не вызывая GetHicon.
см. "[Fast and high quality Bitmap to icon converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627823/Fast-and-high-quality-Bitmap-to-icon-converter)".

---

**UPDATE**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

class Pic : IDisposable {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);    // см. ниже @
    public readonly int Angle;
    public readonly Bitmap Image;
    IntPtr Hicon;
    public Icon Icon;
    Bitmap RotateImage(Image prev, int an) { 
        throw new NotImplementedException();  // todo
    }
    public Pic(int angle, Image original) {
        this.Image = RotateImage(original, angle);
        this.Angle = angle;
        this.Hicon = this.Image.GetHicon();
        this.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(this.Hicon);
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        if (this.Hicon == IntPtr.Zero) return;
        this.Icon.Dispose();
        DestroyIcon(this.Hicon);     // см. ниже @
        this.Hicon = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.Image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  Dictionary<int, Pic> pics;
  int an = 0;      

  public Form1() {
    pics = new Dictionary<int, Pic>();
    pics.Add(new Pic(0, Image=notifyIcon1.Icon.ToBitmap()) );
  }

  void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     var prev = pics[an]; 
     if (an >= 350) an = 0; 
     else an += 10;
     Pic p;
     if (pics.TryGetValue(an, out p) == false) {
       p = new Pic(an, prev.Image);
       pics.Add(p);
     }
     notifyIcon1.Icon = p.Icon;
  }
}
```

**@** для гарантированного вызова DestroyIcon надо использовать специальную обертку над неуправляемым ресурсом. Пример -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483972/196972).

Comment: Очень-очень полезный ответ!!! Как выяснилось, без DestroyIcon, через 6 минут работы приложения возникала ошибка "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида." и Студия подчёркивала notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(RotateImage(btmpIcn, an).GetHicon());

Answer (score 1):

Это не совсем утечка памяти. Со временем мусор будет чиститься, а память освобождаться. Однако, для объектов, реализующих IDisposable надо вызывать Dispose для освобождения ресурсов (в первую очередь unmanaged-ресурсов), как только объект стал не нужен.

Вместо явного вызова Dispose следует использовать блок using, поскольку в нём Dispose вызывается в finally, т. е. его вызов почти гарантирован. Кроме того, это более красивая конструкция в плане кода.

Что касается приведённого кода, то, во-первых, Bitmap обладает unmanaged-ресурсами, но твой код не пытается освободить их вызовом Dispose - ты уничтожаешь только Graphics.

Однако, я бы действовал другим способом. Ясно, что есть ограниченное количество картинок, поэтому я бы сразу создал массив Bitmap'ов с разными поворотами, а в таймере просто менял иконку. Нет смысла на каждой итерации выполнять поворот заново.

И сомнения вызывает необходимость преобразования Icon в Bitmap.

Comment: вызов GetHicon возвращает IntPtr - это дескриптор unmanaged-ресурса, который надо освобождать с помощью DestroyIcon. а вызов Dispose тут не поможет.

Comment: Даже с Dispose программа с каждой секундой увеличивает потребляемую память. Конечно, гораздо меньше чем без него, однако всё равно странно. Идея с массивом изображений мне не по душе. Те же браузеры вращают троббер имея лишь одно изображение. Насчёт преобразования Icon в Bitmap - я не понимаю. Переписать сам метод вращения мне знаний не хватает.

Comment: @Stack, да. Не обратил внимания.

Comment: @Raf-9600, чем не нравится? Браузер вообще не так вращает - он видеокарту использует.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дополнительными действиями не нравится. Каждый раз открывать графический редактор, поворачивать на 10 градусов, сохранять, и потом опять и опять... Мне тут мысль вообще другая пришла. Чтобы создаваемые функцией RotateImage изображения сохранять в массив, и когда их будет достаточно для анимации (в моём случае 35 штук) то уже брать для notifyIcon1 изображения из массива, а не рисовать их через RotateImage. Мне кажется, что это будет компромиссный вариант. И в графический редактор лезть не придётся и CPU меньше будет нагружаться.

Comment: @Raf-9600, "Чтобы создаваемые функцией RotateImage изображения сохранять в массив, и когда их будет достаточно для анимации (в моём случае 35 штук) то уже брать для notifyIcon1 изображения из массива, а не рисовать их через RotateImage" - вот именно это я и имел в виду. Только при запуске программы все сразу сложить в массив. Но можно и твой вариант - может он и лучше даже.

Comment: @Raf-9600 _"изображения сохранять в массив"_ -- т.к. изображение и угол поворота связаны, то можно использовать Diсtionary -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Stack, не вижу смысла в словаре - они же будут последовательно браться - массива вполне хватает.